# Customizing default AbstractColorChooserPanel in Java

Tags: java, swing, colors, jcolorchooser

I want to customize the HSV tab from the JColorChooser.
I'd like to make it more compact (make the slider shorter, move the preview under sliders)

What's the most reasonable way to do it? I know I can set a custom panel and a custom preview myself, but I don't know how to make this nice hsv color picker.

Thanks!.

[image: color panel]

Comment: I honestly don't know where to start. Making a custom model seems too complicated to me. And I see no way to edit existing one.

Answer (score 1):

The panel implementation depends on L&F so you can get the panel for the L&F you need and check LayoutManager and all the components. Then change the LayoutManager to desired one readding all the sub components with desired constraints.

I understand that's too common but it's your requirement.